# Taking a right (or left) limit on a compositon of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose we have functions $f,g\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is left continuous and $g$ is right continuous. I was wondering if **it is always the case that:**

\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\to y_{0}^{-}}(f\circ g)(y) = f(\lim_{y\to y_{0}^{-}} g(y) )  
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_{0}^{+}}(g\circ f)(x) = g(\lim_{x\to x_{0}^{+}} f(x_{0}) )  
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the case, because the function inside can "reverse the order". For example let $g(x) = -x$ and let $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in (-\infty,0]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$. Then
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f(g(x)) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f(-x) = 1 \neq f(0).$$

Also note that if $g$ is only right-continuous, the limit $$\lim\limits_{y\to y_0^-} g(y)$$ need not exist.

Comment: Is there any condition that can be imposed on $f$ or $g$ that implies any of these equalities?

Comment: I think that some additional monotonicity assumption should work (it also implies the existence of one-sided limits at each point). More precisely, both functions should be non-decreasing.